# Consume and Configure Graphql request from .Net C# console application client

Tags: c#, .net, graphql

I'm trying to consume a Graphql Api from a C# client. For that I'm using the GraphQl.Net Nuget package. The problem is that, I have no idea how to set the Api Url as I don't have `HttpRequest` object and this results also with additional problems that I can't set the authentcation header and send the token with the request. My code looks like:

```
public void Post(TestGraphQl.GraphQLQuery query)
{
   var inputs = query.Variables.ToInputs();
   var queryToExecute = query.Query;

   var result = _executer.ExecuteAsync(_ =>
   {
     _.Schema = _schema;
     _.Query = queryToExecute;
     _.OperationName = query.OperationName;
     _.Inputs = inputs;

     //_.ComplexityConfiguration = new ComplexityConfiguration { MaxDepth = 15 };
     _.FieldMiddleware.Use<InstrumentFieldsMiddleware>();

    }).Result;

    var httpResult = result.Errors?.Count > 0
                ? HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
                : HttpStatusCode.OK;

    var json = _writer.Write(result);
}
```

And the caller looks like this:

```
var jObject = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject();
jObject.Add("id", deviceId);
client.Post(new GraphQLQuery { Query = "query($id: String) { device (id: $id) { displayName, id } }", Variables = jObject });
```

I'm totally new to this topic and appreciate any help. Many thanks!!

Comment: What about handling throttling parameters in response while using GraphQLHttpClient??

Answer (score 3):

This worked out for me. You will need the GraphQL.Client Package. My_class is the class for the deserialization.

```
var client = new GraphQLHttpClient(Api_Url, new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());

var request = new GraphQLRequest
{
    Query = {query}
};

var response = await client.SendQueryAsync<my_class>(request);
```

Comment: Can you provide a link, and some background information, to this library?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson Here you go, this should give you a pretty good explanation: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/On-NET/Consuming-GraphQL-in-C

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are still looking for it. One can always use GraphQl.Client nuget to achieve this. Sample code to consume is

```html
var  query = @"query($id: String) { device (id: $id) { displayName, id } }";
var request = new GraphQLRequest(){
                                Query = query,
                                Variables = new {id =123}  
                            };

var graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient("http://localhost:8080/api/GraphQL");

graphQLClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "yourtoken");

var graphQLResponse = await graphQLClient.PostAsync(request);
            
Console.WriteLine(graphQLResponse.Data);
```

Comment: Does query should really be string? Any library to do that based on some schema?

Comment: In my example Graphql.Net client is what I have used. Specifically for query its really a POCO class which is supposed to have these basic building blocks of a graphql query.   Example is                                                                                                                  
 public class GraphQLQueryDTO
    {
        public string OperationName { get; set; }
        public string NamedQuery { get; set; }
        public string Query { get; set; }
        public string Variables { get; set; }
}

Comment: Try this link for a complete example https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/building-and-consuming-graphql-api-in-asp-net-core-3-1/